# How to properly code a time-consuming app installation

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Suppose that, when your activity is launched for the first time, you have to perform the copy of your asset folder content to your private app folder on the smartphone, so that your native c/c++ code can access it (without using the AssetManager on native side). This task can be time-consuming. At the moment, i am doing the following:

1. When the user starts the app, the activity A starts (it is a splash screen actvity and last at least 1500 milliseconds, more if the file copying has to be done). This activity checks if the setup needs to be done. If so, it starts an AsyncTask.
2. The AsyncTask do the installation in the `doInBackground()` method
3. The AsyncTask signal that the installation is done to activity A in the method `onPostExecute()`
4. The activity A finish itself and start the activity B, the main app activity

What is the best strategy to follow to implement it? I am not sure that AsyncTask is the right choice or the whole strategy is the best.